# Aplicar hover desde la posición del cursor

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo el siguiente `html` y `css`, quisiera que el efecto `hover` que tengo dentro del `div` *hijo* se pueda aplicar desde cualquier lugar del `div` *padre* y se propage desde allí mismo, esto es lo que tengo:

```css
.f {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.s {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin: 75px 0px 0px 75px;
  transition: width 1s, height 1s, margin 1s;
}

.s:hover {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="f">
  <div class="s"></div>
</div>
```

Y más o menos esto es lo que quiero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PD: Ya sé que no soy Picasso ni un maestro en photoshop XD

Comment: Mira este enace, no he podido encontrar al menos que se pueda hacer solo con css [enlace](https://www.kirupa.com/snippets/move_element_to_click_position.htm)

Comment: No es posible sin javascript.

Comment: Sin js no es posible por lo que he estado mirando

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Te dejo un solucion con jquery, no he conseguido encontrar la forma de hacerlo solo con html y css

```js
var s = $('.s')
var f = $('.f')
var oTop = f.offset().top + (s.height() / 2);
var oLeft = f.offset().left + (s.width() / 2);

f.hover(function() {
  s.toggleClass('change')
})

f.mousemove(function(e) {
  var x = e.pageY - oTop
  var y = e.pageX - oLeft

  s.css({
    top: x + 'px',
    left: y + 'px'
  })
})
```

```css
.f {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
.s {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: transform 0.5s linear, opacity 0.3s linear;
}
.change {
  transform: scale(2);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="f">
  <div class="s"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Esto era exactamente lo que quería, muchísimas gracias

Comment: Andoni: nótese que he rechazado tu [sugerencia de modificación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32602) de la wiki de una etiqueta, pues no citas las fuentes. Tenlo en cuenta para futuras sugerencias, ¡gracias!

Comment: Ya me he fijado que lo habian rechazado y me he quedado un poco mosca con el asunto. Cuando hablas de fuentes a que te refieres exactamente? He añadido esas dos etiquetas ya que la repuesta aceptada lleva jquery. Aun asi agradezco que te hayas molestado en darme una explicacion. Un saludo

Comment: Andoni, recuerda usar `@fedorqui` si me contestas. Si no, no recibo notificación de que me contestaste (vi tu respuesta por casualidad, ahora). Más info en [¿Cómo funcionan las `@respuestas` en los comentarios?](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/1357/83). En cuanto a la edición en sí, debiste mencionar de dónde la sacabas. Esto se hace utilizando [referencias](/help/referencing). Básicamente, copia (si no tiene copyright) y luego cita la fuente. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 6):

Lo que debes hacer es aplicar un manejador para el evento `mouseover` del padre, de manera que **obtengas las coordenadas** y puedas mover al hijo antes de aplicar la transición. No necesitas jQuery ni ninguna librería, con puro y liviano JavaScript lo puedes hacer en unas pocas líneas.

**Ejemplo**

```js
let father = document.getElementById('f');
let child = document.getElementById('s');

father.addEventListener('mousemove', posicionate);

function posicionate(e) {
  let x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft - 25;
  let y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop - 25;

  child.style.left = `${x}px`;
  child.style.top = `${y}px`;
  /* Solo para quitar el centrado por defecto */
  child.style.bottom = 'auto';
  child.style.right = 'auto';
}
```

```css
.f {
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
}

.s {
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  transition: width 1s, height 1s, margin 1s, opacity .7s;
  width: 50px;
}

.f:hover > .s {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="f" class="f">
  <div id="s" class="s"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 de todas formas, muchas gracias